# How to name the hierarchy of my employees

Tags: single-word-requests

If the employees working directly for him are called his direct reports, how should one call the complete hierarchy of employees who work for him?

Comment: I don't understand why this is so downvoted and voted to close. There may not be a word or generally accepted phrase for it but it's still a viable question. Can any downvoters explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MLM term "downline" means exactly this, but it's frequently used in conjunction with pyramid schemes and the like. "Subordinates" is possible, but that could suggest people below him in other branches and thus not under him. You can use the term "span of control" too by describing them as "employees in his span of control".

If you're going to say "direct reports", why not "direct and indirect reports" or just "reports"?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying subordinates, as I now understand a private would be the subordinate of any general, and not only of his own general. I will simply go with reports then.